# Facebook SDK inside library project throws Dalvik error

Tags: android, facebook, android-library

I am trying to build a library which will be having some activities of it's own that will be included as a part of another Host App.

I want to integrate Facebook SDK inside this library for sharing some content. When I try to include the FB SDK as a library project and then include the library into the host app, I get the

> Dalvik cache with error 1 error

while compiling the Host project.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the issue is without more information, but working with the FacebookSDK, I know I've had a similar issue.

Make sure that the support libraries, `android-support-v4.jar`, or whatever you're using, isn't in both your project and the FacebookSDK project. If you have to pick one or the other, put the `.jar` in the FacebookSDK so both projects can reference it.

Other than that, if you're using eclipse, make sure you clean 17 times, and restart eclipse a few times too. ;)

Comment: It's not android-support-v4.jar, I have already taken care of it. I strongly doubt it's something to do with android.jar or is it not? I am absolutely clueless about this :(